# First ajax call in $.deferred() chain never gets there, but second click on button works fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using `jQuery` to set up a chain of function calls, two of which are ajax calls to `ASP.NET MVC` actions (in the same controller).  Frequently, on the first try, the first AJAX call never gets run and the process hangs.  The breakpoint in the `Action` never gets hit, and the loading dialog shows it's pretty face forever.

A different code path that doesn't have the same function (`thisActionCanHangAjax`) doesn't seem to have issues, but I am not 100% on that.

I can cancel the process (refresh the page, timeout, dismiss dialog).  The second time I click on the button it will go through with no problem, and nice and quick as expected.

I am newish to using jQuery with deferreds/promises, so I am hoping there is something stupid I am doing wrong here (or in the controller, but that doesn't seem likely).

**The jQuery chain and javascript looks like this**:

```
// <input type="button" onclick="fancySubmit()">Go Speed Racer Go</input>

function fancySubmit() {
    jQuery.when()
        .then(openLoadingBox)
        .then(thisActionCanHangAjax) // this one sometimes hangs/etc.  call doesn't reach MVC
        .then(getAdditionalDataAjax)
        .then(submitSimpleForm)
        .done(closeLoading) // modal('hide')
        .fail(showLoadingError);
}

function thisActionCanHangAjax() {
    // POSSIBLE ISSUES HERE?  this action returns JSON on success, but we don't care. 
    // any errors raise a 500 with custom message
    return $.post('@Url.Action("ThisActionCanHangAjax")', $("#basicForm").serialize());
}

function getAdditionalDataAjax() {
    return $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetAdditionalDataAjax")');
}

function submitSimpleForm(jsonDataFrom_getAdditionalDataAjax) {
    // create form and append to body, post form, delete <form> element
    return true;
}

function openLoadingBox() {
    // MAYBE THE ISSUE IS HOW I AM DOING THIS ? 
    var dfd = new jQuery.Deferred(function () { $("#loading-dialog").modal('show'); });
    $("#loading-dialog").on('shown', function () { dfd.resolve(); });
    return dfd.promise();
}
```

**The ASP.NET MVC Pieces are quite simple, tested code**.  Signatures look like this:

```
[HttpPost] public ActionResult ThisActionCanHangAjax(TheModel model)
{
    try { return new JsonNetResult(new { ok = true }); }
    catch (Exception e) { return new HttpStatusCodeResult(500, e.Message); }
}
[HttpGet] public ActionResult GetAdditionalDataAjax() {
    // just reads a bunch of basically static stuff, and returns it.
    return new JsonNetResult(new {name="Paula", level="Brillant" });
}
```

For what it is worth, there is no way for us to debug server side in production, and dev isn't a perfect reproduction (e.g., we don't have a giant IBM mainframe backing this there)  Because of the fact that the action executes fine/fast/is well tested, I don't consider that an issue.  We are simply using the same function as always, but from AJAX and not as part of another action.

Comment: your problem is .when()   - you can't leave that empty , you have to put something in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want :

```
 jQuery.when(openLoadingBox)
        .then(thisActionCanHangAjax) // this one sometimes hangs/etc.  call doesn't reach MVC
        .then(getAdditionalDataAjax)
        .then(submitSimpleForm)
        .done(closeLoading) // modal('hide')
        .fail(showLoadingError);
```

you can't just leave the `.when()` empty like that

of course that commented line never happens and hang, you are saying when nothing is finished , then do this.... so , it never happens

Comment: I'll give that a shot.  The problem is that the dialog box loads up fine, so the first when is obviously going to the next stage.  Previously `openLoadingBox` was not a promise... also, should I return/pass in the deferred (`dfd`) or the `.promise` in this case?

Comment: I've seen examples both ways.  Would calling `.when({})` be ok, because the docs state that anything that is not a promise/deferred is considered resolved immediately

Comment: I believe ({}) is for passing of objects , and checking when they turn into a certain state.  you are passing functions , so I wouldn't go that route.

Comment: and , I don't fully understand what you are trying to do in the openLoadingBox function ,  you can already handle the order and chaning in your .where()   , why are you seperatly dereffing and promise in there??

Comment: Doing that because we need to wait for the bootstrap modal to finish showing before opening the new page.  If we don't do that, then things happen too fast, and 'hide' gets called before the dialog is fully shown, and it gets stuck on the page forever (without the opaque background).  Basically, waiting for the animation to finish and then manually resolving the deferred.

Comment: you have this all wrong then , you cna handle the whole chain in one .where()  , why don't you put .when( something that triggers when bootstarp modal is ready).then( openLoadingBox).then(...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66898/discussion-between-andrew-backer-and-scott-selby).

Comment: Changing it as you suggested doesn't fix it, and returning the deferred instead of the promise doesn't change that.  It just causes the dialog show not be triggered.  I think this needs to be re-written somehow :-/ Damn

Comment: Would you mind editing your post to emphasize changing the order, and putting the "submit" path in the "shown" event, after the box is visible.  I'll mark it accepted then.  This helped a lot, but it also turned out we were having a horrible delay (up to a minute) calling the first step for some reason on the server side.